# PHP/MySQL returning no result on some queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know this is not a new question, but I'm having inconsistency between results when running the same queries with different parameters:

The problem begins with this query  (copy pasted from the script log):

```
SELECT id 
FROM Resources 
WHERE group_id IN (2,3,1) 
AND MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('diseño' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
LIMIT 10
```

which outputs nothing, num_rows is 0 and any attempts to parse it fails. Curiously enough, if I paste that same query in phpMyadmin it returns 9 results.

now this is a working query from the exact same function and process:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Resources 
WHERE group_id IN (2,3,1) 
AND MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('moda' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
LIMIT 10
```

This spits out 10 results and works normally.

This is my code:

```
public function loadFromSearch($searchStr, $resourceGroupIdList){
    //$searchStr2 = NaturalLanguageHelper::mb_replace('n', 'ñ', $searchStr);

    $dbConn = new DbConnection();
    $query = $dbConn->escapeQuery("SELECT {$this->DB_ID} FROM {$this->DB_TABLE_NAME} WHERE {$this->DB_GROUP_ID} IN ({$resourceGroupIdList}) AND MATCH ({$this->DB_FULLTEXT_INDEX}) AGAINST ('%s' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) LIMIT 10", $searchStr);

    Log::echo("\n". $query . "\n\n");

    $result = $dbConn->newQuery($query);
    return $this->fillArrayFromResult($result, array('title'));
}
```

This calls this function:

```
protected function fillArrayFromResult($result, $column_list_array = false) {
        Log::echo("\nnum rows: {$result->num_rows}\n\n");
        if($result->num_rows == 0)return false;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){

            Log::echo("\n\nGot Row! Creating instance of ".$this->class."...\n");

            $instance = new $this->class();

            Log::echo("\n\n Instance OK\n");

            if(!is_array($column_list_array))
                $instance->loadFromDb($row[0]);
            else
                $instance->loadFromDbPartial($column_list_array, $row[0]);

            array_push($this->collection, $instance);
        }
        $result->free();
        return true;
    }
```

And here is the Query function:

```
public function newQuery($query){
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query))
            return $result;
        else
            ErrorHandler::throwError("MySQL Query Error: (" . $this->mysqli->errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->error);
    }
```

Any idea whats going on? and thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be an encoding problem

Comment: Did you set the character set of the mysqli connection?

Comment: Show us your database connection code (remove passwords)

Comment: @RiggsFolly are you thinking about `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;CharSet=utf8;` connection string?

Comment: Yes that is what I was wanting to see. Did I miss that in the code somewhere? @Cid

Comment: Please add the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Resources`.  I agree this is most likely an issue with character set mismatch between client and database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly not at all, I did some searches after your comment and realised we can use charset in connection strings

Comment: Hopefully @Arheisel is also following our thread as well

Comment: it was indeed an encoding problem, database is in latin1 and php in utf8, thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out it was an encoding problem, the database is in latin1 and the code in utf8, using utf_decode in the query before sending it solved my problems.

Thank you everyone!